# Can a webpage open in Safari crash the whole computer?

Tags: macos, safari, crash, performance

I have a Mid-2011 MacBook Air. Everything seems to be working fine, except Safari keeps freezing and stops responding. Sometimes, when Safari freezes, it causes the whole computer to crash and I have to restart it.

I thought browsers were supposed to have security measures that prevent this from happening (like Sandboxing). How can a webpage crash the whole OS?

Comment: can you provide the url of a page which causes this problem?  do you have the same problem with FireFox or Chrome?

Comment: Do @TomGewecke suggestion first. Subsequently,  open your **Console.app**, located in `/Appications/Utilities/Console`. Update the original post with the contents of your most recent `com.apple.safari…` or `com.apple.webkit….` log under “System Diagnostic Reports”

Comment: I figured out the answer. It was because of Flash.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption solution:
Safari is continuously attempting to reload the last session.
To resolve this issue go to `~/Library/Saved Application State/`
Remove the com.safari... folder and place in the Trash.

A second issue could be adware, which created the issue in the first place. 
Open Safari, which should operate properly after removing the above folder, and go to [AdwareMedic](http://www.adwaremedic.com) .
Download and run the free program and that will remove any adware.